# Aws ecs task IP address stop working after some time for nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ecs

I deployed sample node app container on AWS ECS Fargate, and obtain the public Ip of the task it running.The public Ip only works for few minutes, seconds some times. Nothing logs in cloudwatch as an error, and the sample app is just returning a json nothing more.

[this image shows when service is started, and after multiple reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKlam.png)

[This image show after few minutes task is running but public  ip not accesible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl3CN.png)

Comment: cek you service logs

docker logs <service name>

Comment: nothing is logged except for the console about the app running, No message on crash or anyother stuffs. btw i am using cloudwatch to check the container

Comment: I'm experimenting the same behavior. How did you solve it?